Can a verb come after the word "repeat"?
I hardly see any verb coming after the word "repeat".

He repeated saying "Oh, no!" five times.

Is it OK to say like this?

You say you hardly [ever] see this. Have you ever seen it? Where? I suppose in principle it's syntactically valid, since it's structurally the same as He repeated it five times, and saying "Oh, no!" is a noun-like gerund element. But i don't think it's idiomatically valid. We might say He said "Oh, no!" five times (it's unnecessary to explicitly include repeat, because that's already implied by five times). But if you wanted to emphasize the repetition you could just say He repeated "Oh, no!" five times.

Actually, I have never seen any. Thank you very much for your explanation, which I couldn't find anywhere on the Internet. Now I can confidently say verbs don't come after "repeat".

It's a good question, though I don't think there's any syntactic reason for rejecting your made-up example. It's just relatively non-idiomatic, but I'm quite certain it's syntactically valid without five times, and it's difficult to justify the claim that including that adverbial element in and of itself is syntactically invalid - even though if you do, it becomes 100% unacceptable, rather than just "unusual".

Where FumbleFingers and I agree is that this sort of construction is not something native speakers say. It is not how the overwhelming majority of native speakers would express the fact.

Temporarily ignoring the syntactically irrelevant adverbial element five times in this context, OP's example...

1: He repeated saying "Oh, no!"
...is structurally identical to...
2: The rat repeated pressing the bar

...which obviously got past the publisher's proofreading, since it's there in Google Books. But idiomatically we're far more likely to use

1a: He said "Oh, no!" repeatedly
...which is structurally identical to...
2a: The rat pressed the bar repeatedly

...where I included links to both the "rat/bar" examples because they both made it into print. But it's important to note that although my second pair are much more common, we can't validly attach adverbial five times, because it clashes with adverbial repeatedly.
I should also point out that when we use to repeat with a non-gerund-based complement, it can have contextually different meanings...

3: He repeated the words five times  (to repeat = to say)
4: He repeated the action five times  (to repeat = to do)


TLDR: The OP's example is syntactically valid, but it should be avoided because it's not very idiomatic. Particularly when adverbially modified by things like five times, twice, often, which I think no native speaker would ever endorse.

I disagree that they're syntactically "identical".

Good luck defending that position! I'm not gonna bother attacking it in detail, but obviously I disagree!

since you've obviously downvoted, I'll flag up two slight variations that are syntactically identical in exactly the same way... 1) Saying goodbye is a waste of time and 2) Shutting the door is a waste of time. I have nothing more to add, here.

You're not addresing the very point on which we disagree.  "saying goodbye" is not the same as "saying 'goodbye' ".  I think saying "oh, no" (directly quoted phrase) resists becoming a gerund in a way that "emptying her purse" and "saying goodbye" do not.  "Some people hate saying goodbye" is fine and it's a gerund there.

Okay, just one final point. It's completely irrelevant that I could have chosen 1a) Saying "Goodbye" is a waste of time for my first example there. Language (particularly as regards syntax) is essentially spoken, and in speech you couldn't differentiate the two orthographies anyway.

I'm not talking about an orthographic difference but about direct quotation, which is a form of speech-act apart from how it is represented in writing.

She repeated [the act of] emptying her purse  vs.   She repeated [the act of] saying Oh no.  I don't think the specific unique speech-act wants to be gerundized, so to speak.

The direct object of repeat is what is said more than once.

He repeated the warning.
She repeated those words several times.
The little train repeated I think I can over and over again.

If you see a verb form after the word repeated and its understood subject and the subject of "repeat" are the same subject, that verb is not an object but something else:

Those words he repeated, saying them much louder than he did the first time.

Your sentence:

He repeated saying "Oh, no!" five times.

is ungrammatical as is, but you could repunctuate:

He repeated, saying "Oh, no!" five times.

In that case "repeated" is intransitive. The sentence is not quite idiomatic, however. This would be OK:

He repeated himself, saying "Oh, no!" five more times.

Or this:

He said "Oh no!" repeatedly, saying it five times.

But if you are simply trying to say that he said the words "Oh no!" five times, it would be:

He repeated the words "Oh no!" five times.

P.S. With repeated actions, however, the situation is different. It can be followed by a nominal form of the verb:

She repeated emptying her pocketbook out onto the table and  putting the items back in again for the entire time we were there.


If you can say "she repeated emptying her pocketbook" why can't you use the same syntax in "he repeated saying 'Oh, no!'"

@Barmar I'd point out that native speakers don't say things like "She repeated saying her name over and over" but would say instead "She kept saying her name over and over".  So there's already an idiomatic way to say this. Also, an action like emptying a pocketbook lends itself to nominalization (as a recognizable action) far more readily than saying {random phrase} does. Why? Because {random phrase} adds uniqueness to the speech-act, which is like adding ethylene-glycol to water to prevent it from freezing. It resists nominalization.

Of course, there's differences between whether something is grammatical, idiomatic, or common.

@Barmar  I think OP needs advice on how to communicate in English, not a discussion of what is remotely possible.  My P.S. goes down the "remotely possible" rabbit hole and I regret adding it.

My understanding is that it is OK to used verbs with "ing" after "repeat" in the case that there are two or more actions done repeatedly, like jump, squat, jump, squat....
Anyway, thank you very much for your explanation. It is clear enough to be able to explain to my colleagues!

What @Barmar said. "she repeated emptying her pocketbook" is syntactically identical to "he repeated saying 'Oh, no!'". And imho both of them are equally "non-idiomatic" (but obviously they're also equally "syntactically valid"). It's true that to repeat can be used on its own to mean to say [some utterance, but it can also mean to do [some action] in other contexts.

@Filitheyo  I'm not sure what you mean by "OK".  It's not idiomatic, so in that sense it is not OK. Please give an example sentence that you think is OK.

There's a difference between grammatically OK and idiomatically OK. There are phrases that are grammatical that we don't normally use, and vice versa.

@TimR, is this idiomatically OK?
He repeated taking the purse out of the pocket and putting it back.

@Filitheyo  I would so no, it is not how a native speaker is likely to express it. To me it sounds like someone who is learning English.  "She kept taking the purse out of her pocket and putting it back" or "She repeatedly took her purse out of her pocket and put it back again." or "She took the purse out of her pocket and put it back over and over again".

For that version, or something like it, to be idiomatic, we would have to turn to a psychologist's observational write-up of a patient's aberrant behavior and in that case the phrasing is likely to be more formal:  She repeated the action of taking the purse out of her pocket and returning it.  "She repeated taking" is in a limbo between the idiomatic and the unidiomatic.
